# Linux Opencv: How can i convert a video frame to a Floating point single-channel format (32 bpp) matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, bitmap

I read a video using :

```
video = VideoCapture(<video source>);
```

and retrieve each video frame as a cv::Mat

```
video >> frame;
```

How can i convert the 'frame' mat to a Floating point single-channel format (32 bpp) ?

Comment: 16bit data would be short integers (0-65535). Floats would be 32bit. Which do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If your Mat is 3 channel RGB and you want a single channel float, you will need to convert to grayscale first and then to float:

```
cv::cvtColor(frame, greyMat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
greyMat.convertTo(floatMat,CV_32F);
```